# Translating Java while loop into ARM Assembly?

Tags: java, assembly, while-loop, arm, cpu-architecture

I want to translate some Java code that calculates the sum from the below loop to ARM assembly, and I am wondering: how I can fix what I have so far?

Here is the Java code I am translating:

```
R0 = 0; 
R1 = 1;
while (R1 < 100) 
{
  R0 += R1;
  R1++;
}
```

And here is the code in ARM Assembly:

```
  MOV       R0,#0
  MOV       R1,#1
  MOV       R2,#100 
looptop
  CMP       R0, R2
  BGT       loopbottom

  ADD       R0, R0, R1
  ADD       R1, R1, #1
  B         looptop 
loopbottom
```

Comment: The `while (R1 < 100)` obviously uses `R1` but your assembly uses `R0`.

Comment: Also the original loop does not run for `R1 == 100` but your assembly does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to initialize `r2` since you can use the immediate value of 100 with `cmp`:

```
    mov     r1, #1
    mov     r0, #0
1
    cmp     r1, #100
    add     r0, r0, r1
    add     r1, r1, #1
    blt     %b1
```

---

You can remove the `cmp` instruction altogether by constructing the loop with decreasing, zero-terminating counter:

```
    mov     r1, #100
    mov     r0, #0
1
    subs    r1, r1, #1
    addgt   r0, r0, r1
    bgt     %b1
```

Comment: I understand a little better now thanks to your explanation. I appreciate it.ㄱㅅ!